# OneToOneField empty from both sides

Tags: python, django, models

is there any way to create a OneToOneField, which can be empty on both sides?

I mean if i' ve this relation between `ModelA` and `ModelB`, i want to allow `ModelA` not having a `ModelB` relatioship, and `ModelB` not having a `ModelA` relationship.

In my example there' s this code:

`class Forum(models.Model):

    .....



class Jobs(models.Model):

    forum = models.OneToOneField(Forum, blank = True, null = True)`

. This works pretty well from `Jobs -> Forum` direction, but when i try it from `Forum -> Jobs` direction, certainly i get `query does not exist` error.

As a workaround i could use `ManyToManyField` or `hasattr` to check it, but i' d be interested rather in a OneToOneField like solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should create an access method for the reverse relationship.

Have a look how Django's User model implements this with [get_profile](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L413).